# SQL complex calculation

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, aggregation

Calculate P&L of each security in SQL

```
security side   quantity price
AAPL     BUY   2000     110.00
MSFT    BUY   1000      40.00
MSFT    SELL   500      38.00
```

Result should look like:

```
security realized_p&l
MSFT      -1000.00
AAPL
```

Comment: how is this complex?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I'm tempted to answer something like `SELECT 'MSFT' security, -1000.00 realized_p&l UNION ALL SELECT 'AAPL', NULL;`... Seriously, try to describe what you want, not just toss **only** an example. Examples are fine and welcome for clarification **along with an explanation**. Without any explanation they're at best ambiguous, if one could even figure an (not the) idea what's behind it. In other words: useless.

Answer (score 0):

P&LRealized is sell price minus buy price times qty of sell.

```
select a.`security`,
case when b.side is not null
then (b.price-a.price) * b.quantity
else '' end "realized_p&l"
from tbl a
left join tbl b
on a.`security`=b.`security` and b.side='SELL'
where a.side='BUY' 

result: 
security    realized_p&l
MSFT    -1000
AAPL
```